# easiest way to transform array into matrix using java-script

Tags: javascript

I have written down my first JavaScript code to do some dynamic rendering in a webpage:

```js
var c_names = ["Canada", "USA", "israel"]
var c_ids = [1, 2, 3]
var c_domaain = ["www.canada.com", "www.usa.com", "www.israel.com"]

var data_1 = []
var C_data = [
  ['Country', 'ids', 'Domain']
]
var x = 1


for (i = 0; i == 3; i++) {
  var x = x + 1
  data_1.push(c_name[x], c_ids[x], c_domain[x])
  for (i = 0; i < c_name.length; i++) {
    C_data.push(data_1)
  }
}

console.log(C_data)
```

I'm expecting this output:

```
 data = [ ['Country', 'ids', 'Domain'],
           ['USA', 1, 'www.usa.com'],
           ['Canada', 2, 'www.usa.com'],
           ['Israel', 3, 'www.usa.com'],
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over one of the arrays and then append the respective items.

```js
var names   = ["Canada", "USA", "israel"]
var ids     = [1, 2, 3]
var domains = ["www.canada.com", "www.usa.com", "www.israel.com"]

var data = [
    ["Country", "ID", "Domain"]
]

names.forEach ((name, idx) => {
    data.push ([ name, ids [idx], domains [idx]]);
});

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var c_names = ["Canada","USA","israel" ];
var c_ids =  [1,2,3];
var c_domaain = ["www.canada.com","www.usa.com","www.israel.com"];

var data_1 = [];
var C_data = ['Country', 'ids', 'Domain'];
var x = 1;

for(var i = 0; i < c_names.length; i++){
  data_1.push(new Array(C_data[i], c_names[i], c_domaain[i]));
};
console.log(data_1);
```

This is the output of your code which is wrong:

```
[ [ "Country", "ids","Domain"],
  [ "Canada", 1, "Country"],
  [  "USA",  2,  "ids" ],
  [  "israel", 3, "Domain"]
]
```

Comment: A little mistake with values... c_ids[i] instead of C_data[i].

Comment: I have edited your answer to show output kindly check your code Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could take the array in one array and iterate the outer and the the inner array while respecting the index.

```js
var c_names = ["Canada", "USA", "israel"],
    c_ids = [1, 2, 3],
    c_domaain = ["www.canada.com", "www.usa.com", "www.israel.com"],
    c_data = ['Country', 'ids', 'Domain'],
    result = [c_names, c_ids, c_data].reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(function (b, i) {
            r[i] = r[i] || [];
            r[i].push(b);
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

result.unshift(c_data);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var c_names = ["Canada", "USA", "israel"]
var c_ids = [1, 2, 3]
var c_domaain = ["www.canada.com", "www.usa.com", "www.israel.com"]
var C_data = [
  ['Country', 'ids', 'Domain']
]
var i = -1;
while ( c_names[++i] ) { 
  C_data.push( [ c_names[i], c_ids[i], c_domaain[i]] );
}
console.log(C_data)
```